# Add calculation name on dataset statistics

Tags: dataset

I am working on, with the `Animal Weights` data set and creating `MyFunction`which calculates the Max,Min,Mean,Median and first quartile. Then a apply the function to the data set and show it as a menu with `MenuView`. My question is, is there a possible way to use add the calculation name in the data set object? Like in the image below.

```
 ResourceObject["Sample Data: Animal Weights"];
dataset = ResourceData["Sample Data: Animal Weights"];

MyFunction[dataset_] :=
 {Max[dataset], Min[dataset], Mean[dataset], Median[dataset], 
  Quantile[dataset, 0.25]}

MenuView[{"BodyWeight" -> dataset[MyFunction, "BodyWeight"], 
  "BrainWeight" -> dataset[MyFunction, "BrainWeight"]}]
```

[image: img 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ResourceObject["Sample Data: Animal Weights"];
dataset = ResourceData["Sample Data: Animal Weights"];

MyFunction[
  dataset_] := {# /. _Function :> "1st Quartile", #[dataset]} & /@ 
     {Max, Min, Mean, Median, Quantile[#, 0.25] &}

MenuView[{"BodyWeight" -> dataset[MyFunction, "BodyWeight"], 
  "BrainWeight" -> dataset[MyFunction, "BrainWeight"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: I don´t understand why the set delayed and the _Function?

Comment: Look at `{Max, Min, Mean, Median, Quantile[#, 0.25] &} // FullForm` The last element needs to be handled differently.

Comment: Oh , I see now.